# Determine if element with id was clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to use an event listener to trigger a function if a specific element has been clicked. Below you will see that there are 3 elements which share the "gameselection" class, each with a unique id.

I have so far managed to get the event listener to trigger if I look for a specific class that has been clicked. But I need to amend the functionality so that it looks for an element with a  class and id combination.

Here is the element's HTML:

```
<div class="gameselections">
    <div class="gameselection" id="rockdiv">
        <p class="gameselectiontext" id="rockselection">Rock</p>
        <img class="selection" src="images/rock.png">
    </div>
    <div class="gameselection" id="paperdiv">
        <p class="gameselectiontext" id="paperselection">Paper</p>
        <img class="selection" src="images/paper.png">
    </div>
    <div class="gameselection" id="scissorsdiv">
        <p class="gameselectiontext" id="scissorsselection">Scissors</p>
        <img class="selection" src="images/scissors.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS, which works for a specified class:

```
document.addEventListener("click", gameSelectionListener);
function gameSelectionListener(event) {
    let element = event.target;
    console.log(event.target);
    let rock = "rock";
    if (element.classList.contains("gameselection")) {
        playRound(rock);
        console.log("submitted rock")
    }
}
```

I know that I need to amend the JS to include two criteria; however, I'm not sure what that looks like. Here's what I thought would work:

```
// Event listener for click
document.addEventListener("click", gameSelectionListener);
// Check and see if the click was on a game selection button (can't apply directly on button as div hidden initially)
function gameSelectionListener(event) {
    let element = event.target;
    console.log(event.target);
    let rock = "rock";
    if (element.classList.contains("gameselection") && element.id.contains("rockdiv")) {
        playRound(rock);
        console.log("submitted rock")
    }
}
```

Here's the error being reported in the JS console using the above code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.id.contains is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.gameSelectionListener (main.js:54)
```

Comment: `element.id === "rockdiv"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method contains() wont work since your trying to execute it on a string

You can reach your elemnt id by

```
event.target.id
```

And your if statement can look like this

```
if (element.classList.contains("gameselection") && element.id == "rockdiv") {
    playRound(rock);
    console.log("submitted rock")
}
```

"contains" is a function that will work on nodes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains